# Having trouble iterating and printing Strings in ArrayList

Tags: java

I get results such as

device@3d4eac69
device@42a57993
device@75b84c92
device@6bc7c054
device@232204a1

From my understanding these numbers are the location of the data, but i want to actually print the Strings within the lists. I've been at this for awhile today and can't seem to figure it out. This is an attempt to make a prettier version of a 2d ArrayList program I had that did the job.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class device {
private String sku;
private String name;
private boolean available;
static ArrayList<device> devices = new ArrayList<device>();

public device()
{
    
}

public device(String sku, String name, boolean isAvailable) 
{
    this.sku = sku; 
    this.name = name;
    this.available = isAvailable;
}

public String getStatusString() {
    
    return available ? "Available" : "Checked out";
}

public String devicePrint() 
{
    return String.format("SKU: %s, Name: %s, Status: %s", this.sku, this.name, this.getStatusString());
}




public void addDefaultDevices()
{
    devices.add(new device("6767A", "Apple 9.7-Inch iPad Pro", true));
    devices.add(new device("93P51B", "Amazon Kindle Fire Kids Edition", true));
    devices.add(new device("10N8C", "LeapFrog Epic Learning Tablet", true));
    devices.add(new device("85U20", "Amazon Kindle Fire HD 8", false));
    devices.add(new device("91H2D", "HP Envy Note 8", true));
    
}





import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MP2 {

static device deviceObj = new device();
static Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    

    deviceObj.addDefaultDevices();
    
    
    deviceObj.devices.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Nowhere are you calling `devicePrint`. If you want your objects to be used with `println` directly, you have to override `Object#toString()`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined a `toString()` method for the class `device`:

Either:

```
public String toString() {
    return devicePrint();
}
```

Or just replace `devicePrint()` with `toString()` (which is the conventional way):

```
public String toString() {
    return String.format("SKU: %s, Name: %s, Status: %s", this.sku, this.name, this.getStatusString());
}
```

---

Side note: Java naming convention has class names starting with capital letter, so `class Device` rather than `class device`.

And variable names are generally the camelcase version of the class name, ie:

```
static Device device = new Device();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also solve your problems without much adjustment by using lambda.

```
deviceObj.devices.forEach((n) -> System.out::println(n.devicePrint()));
```

As it is shown [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arraylist-foreach-method-in-java/) in the second example

I myself am relatively new to Java so all information without guarantee :-)

Answer (score -2):

Print the strings with help of "+" operator instead of "%s".

```java
public String toString() {
    return "SKU: " + this.sku + ", Name: " + this.name + ", Status: " + this.getStatusString();
}
```

In Java "+" operator is used instead of "%s" (or format specifier) operator! And use toString method instead of "devicePrint()".

Comment: I get SKU: null, Name: null, Status: Checked out